# cmake -E copy with wildcards and build time variable

Tags: cmake

I want to have a macro to copy files looking like this:

```
MACRO(POST_BUILD_COPY src_files dest_path)
    ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${src_files} ${dest_path})
ENDMACRO(POST_BUILD_COPY src_files dest_path)
```

This is perfectly fine in most cases. My problem is that `src_files` can be something like `path/to/${CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR}/headers/*.h`.

The problems are

- `cmake -E copy` (nor `copy_directory`) does not seem to be able to handle the wildcard
- `file(GLOB files ${src_files})` resolves to an empty array since it is evaluated at the configuration time and `${CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR}` is a build time variable (which is for example `$(Configuration)` for msvc)

Is there a cmake way to tackle this problem that I am missing ? I do not want to rely on external tools (this is what we do right now, and it leads to other issues we want to get rid of)

Comment: You may create separate CMake script which glob files (`file(GLOB)`) and copy them (`file(COPY)`). Execute this script with `COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} <...-D params> -P <script>`.